# Changing iOS App Icon remotely via push notification

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, capacitor, onesignal

I have an iOS application that is using push notifications & alternate icons. I can dynamically change the app's icon when in the foreground. But I want to change the app's icon via a server trigger, such as a silent/data push notification.

Can I trigger the [setAlternateIconName()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname) method via a push notification? If so where should I write this logic?

The application is Ionic Capacitor application & uses Firebase or Onesignal depending on the configuration. Here's my existing AppDelegate.Swift file.

```swift
import UIKit
import Capacitor
import FBSDKCoreKit

#if USE_FIREBASE
import Firebase
#endif

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
      FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
      application,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
    )
    
    #if USE_FIREBASE
    // Firebase for push notifications
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    #endif
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
  }

  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if (FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
      app,
      open: url,
      sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
        annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
    )) {
      return true;
    } else {
        return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
      }
    }
  
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    #if USE_FIREBASE
      // Capacitor-Firebase
      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
      Messaging.messaging().token(completion: { (token, error) in
          if let error = error {
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .capacitorDidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications, object: error)
          } else if let token = token {
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .capacitorDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications, object: token)
          }
      })
    #else
      // OneSignal
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .capacitorDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications, object: deviceToken)
    #endif
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .capacitorDidFailToRegisterForRemoteNotifications, object: error)
  }


}
```

Comment: Did you try to do it in a background task on receiving the notification? The notification should wake your app up in background (unless the app was killed by the user, of course.)